# Javascript onmousehover event to connect information

Tags: javascript

So in my code I created a table pulling from an XML file that displayed two columns of information about plants. The goal of my program is to be able to hover over the first  and print out the other information about that plant and print it in another section to the right of my table. The issue is that I am not gettign any console errors and the hover affect is not printing any information.

```
window.addEventListener("load", link_events);
var xhr = false;
function link_events() {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if(xhr) {
            xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", ShowFile);
            xhr.open("GET", "plants.xml", true);
            xhr.send();
        } else {
            alert("XHR not supported.");
        }
}
function ShowFile() {
    var i;
    var title;
    var cover;
    var plant_table = "<table><tr><th>Common Name </th><th>Botanical Name </th></tr>";
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
        //here we have gotten the file correctly
        //loop through it and print out cover and title
        var plantlist = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("PLANT");
        //booklist is an array and each element is an object sub i 
        //so you have to use getElementBy something in order to pull the information
        for (i = 0; i < plantlist.length; i++) {
            var Common = plantlist[i].getElementsByTagName("COMMON")[0].firstChild.textContent;
             var Botanical = plantlist[i].getElementsByTagName("BOTANICAL")[0].firstChild.textContent;
            plant_table += "<tr>" +
                            "<td class =\"plant\">" + Common + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + Botanical + "</td>" +
                         "</tr>";
    }
        plant_table += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("outarea").innerHTML = plant_table;
    }
    var plants = document.getElementsByClassName("plant");
    for (i=0; i < plants.length; i++) {
      plants[i].onmouseover = HoverChoice;
    }
    }
function HoverChoice() {
    var input = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("PLANT");
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            Common = input[i].getElementsByTagName("COMMON")[0].firstChild.textContent;
            var Zone = input[i].getElementsByTagName("ZONE")[0].firstChild.textContent;
            var Light = input[i].getElementsByTagName("LIGHT")[0].firstChild.textContent;
           var Price = input[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].firstChild.textContent; 
    if (plants == this.innerHTML) {
    document.getElementById("inarea").innerHTML = 
    "<h1>" + Common + "</h1>" + "<br />" + "<br />" +
    "Zone: " + Zone + "<br />" +
    "Light: " + Light + "<br />" +
    "Price: " + Price;
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: where are you triggering `hover` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but to my understanding, you want to hover the "common" data and display the "botanical" data in a block beside your table? is that it?

Comment: im actually trying to print different information from the XML frile when i hover that info would be the zone light and price

Answer (score 0):

you could try using addEventListener method instead and see whether it works?

```
    plants.forEach(function(plant){
    plant.addEventListener("onmouseover", HoverChoice);
    });
```

or going with the original loop you made it would be

```
for (i=0; i < plants.length; i++) 
{
  plants[i].addEventListener("onmouseover", HoverChoice);
}
```

I'm not anything professional, a common problem I used to encounter in these kinds of event listening functions was that calling a global function sometimes fails but making the function on the spot inside the event listener would work like addEventListener("onmouseover" , function() { return 0; });